# simplfy and apply Demorgan law to the f(a , b,c)

Tags: logic, boolean-operations, demorgans-law

given this function

```
F(a,b,c) = aba + c’ab + c’b’ + c’b + b’cb + abc
```

ask as to simplfy it ..

Use DeMorgan’s law to find the complement `F’(a,b,c)` of `F(a,b,c)`?

I simplfy it and get this answer 
    `=c'+ab`
but I am not sure if that's correct.

These are my steps:

```
F(a,b,c) = *aba* + c’ab + c’b’ + c’b + *b’cb* + abc 
= *ab* + abc’+ abc + c’(b’+b) + *c(0)*  
= *ab* + ab(c’+ c )+ c’(1) + 0
= *ab* + ab(1)+ c’ 
= *ab* + c’
```

then I apply the DeMorgan law 
and this is my answer can any one please check it because when I try to simplify it I get the wrong answer even when I check it using truth table:

```
F'(a,b,c) = aba + c’ab + c’b’ + c’b + b’cb + abc 
=(aba + c’ab + c’b’ + c’b + b’cb + abc)’
= (aba )’. (c’ab )’.( c’b’ )’. (c’b )’. (b’cb)’ . (abc)’
by distribute the not ’
=(a’+b’+a’) . (c+a’+b’) . (c+b) . (c+b’) . (b+c’b’) . (a’b’c’)
```

Comment: How is it related to Mathematica (as opposed to mathematics)?

Comment: Note that you're only simplifying the original function, not its complement. Please show how you compute the complement of the simplified function.